# How can I change the content with JavaScript / jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a dynamic element in javascript and change the content and append that to the body, buy not works

```
var template = "<div class='ooo'>old message</div>";
$(template).find(".ooo").html("new message");
$("body").append(template);
```

it return **old message** , it seem that JQUERY directly work with internal DOM,

http://jsfiddle.net/gL9GR/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modifying the jQuery object will not update the string literal from which it was created

```
var template = "<div class='ooo'>old message</div>";
var $tmpl = $(template);
$tmpl.filter(".ooo").html("new message");
$("body").append($tmpl);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Be4A8/)

Also in the given template you need to use .filter() instead of .find() because $tmpl refers to the `.ooo` element - you can even completely remove that because there is only one element in `$tmpl`

- [Without any filtering](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Be4A8/3/)
- [using .find()](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Be4A8/4/)

Comment: May I know why filter on direct <div class='ooo'>old message</div> not working ? it seem that find has a bug

Comment: Yes, it works, but why find not works on sample one?, do you know ?

Comment: @Ata `find()` will not work because it searches for an descendant element but in your template there are no descendants matching the given selector